# What's wrong with my batch script?

Tags: scripting

I want to batch packing every single object's UV. But the script can't go throw everyone. After packing one object, it stopped with no error. What's wrong?

*(I've already did Cube Projection for all objects beforehand.)*

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    obj.select_set(True)

    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
    bpy.ops.uv.pack_islands(margin=0.001)
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to some silly mistakes. This one works.

```
import bpy

objs = bpy.context.selected_objects

for obj in objs:
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    obj.select_set(True)
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj

    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
    bpy.ops.uv.pack_islands(margin=0.001)
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
```